# 1and1 hosting: Data migration from shared hosting to VPS

Tags: php, mysql, shared-hosting, data-migration, vps

I am doing this first time so I need some help. I am using 1and1 hosting. I want to migrate a domain from shared hosting package to virtual server. This [link](http://faq.1and1.com/domains/domain_xfers/internal_xfers/4.html) shows how to migrate domain but shows this warning:

*Before transferring a domain, please backup all website files, databases, e-mail accounts, and take note of any DNS settings or subdomains created under the domain as `no data or configuration will transfer with the domain`!*

I just want some general guidelines to `transfer data and configuration`. I could not find any tutorial on this.

PS> one site is WordPress based and the other is simply PHP/MySQL based.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no data or configuration will transfer with the domain!

This just refers to the things listed there. You will need to copy them to your new server.

- website files
- databases
- e-mail accounts
- DNS settings or subdomains

Files can be easily copied and database systems usually have an easy import/export feature. Other configuration is often not available as a file, but only over a web interface. Probably some forms and text fields, which you should take note off since you can't just copy and paste this information if there is no export feature. If you want to make sure: screenshot everything. There are other configuration settings you might need, like the PHP version or additional PHP modules or cronjobs.

Comment: thanks! What should be the order of doing things? I think I should first take backups and then transfer them to the new server and then follow the instructions on the mentioned links.

Comment: I think the order in which you backup the data doesn't really matter. If you don't have used any special server configuration, copying a backup of the files and the database could be enough for wordpress to run (don't forget to change wordpress' configuration to use the new database). If you already have the virtual server, use the backup to get it running there and if everything work, transfer the domain.

Comment: I did migration but some links are not working :( Any suggestion? Please see [this](http://bit.ly/sBAlAn)